# javascript convert string to object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var string = "{lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312};{lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181};{lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124}"
var array = string.split(';');
```

Results in:

```
var array = [
    "{lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312}",
    "{lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181}",
    "{lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124}"
  ]
```

Tried using `JSON.parse(array);` but receive a SyntaxError

The array I am trying to achieve would look like this:

```
var array = [
    {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
    {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
    {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124}
  ]
```

Comment: if you want to use `JSON.parse` you need to wrap keys with `"`

Comment: Where is this `string` coming from?  Can you go back to its source and have it given as a proper JSON string?

Comment: The point is: IF that string were properly formatted JSON, you could simply do `var array = JSON.parse( string );` and be done.  If you have control over how that string is generated, you probably need to get it formatted properly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
string = string
  .replace(/lat/g, '"lat"')
  .replace(/lng/g, '"lng"')
  .replace(/;/g, ',')
JSON.parse('[' + string + ']')
```

How does this work?

- `replace` is used to add quotes around keys
- `replace` is used to turn semicolons into commas
- Then string is wrapped into `[...]` and thus valid json

And as mentioned in the comments, if that string were properly formatted JSON you could simply parse it. Thus if you have control over how that string is generated, maybe best fix it there.

Comment: using regular expressions 3 times and JSON.parse afterwards is highly not optimal solution

Comment: @pwolaq it is very readable. No need for premature optimization. And even then, using 3 regex with string literals is sure more efficient than one regexp with string manipulation in the replace function.

Comment: you could achieve op's goal with one regex and without JSON.parse

Comment: And what would be the point of that? Code is written for people not for machines, all the other answers to this questions are unreadable code.

Answer (score -2):

You are almost there. You would want to run every value in `array` through the function `JSON.parse()` to get a javascript value.

```
array[z] = JSON.parse(array[z]);
```

Edit: Though your json isn't quite in the correct format.